# Shiny Icon to tabset panels

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a tabset panel in my shiny dashboard that will populate for however many values there are.  I want to add an option that will add an icon next to the name in the tabset panel if a criteria is met and to return just the name if it is not like the following:

```
library(shinydashboard)
nba_teams <- data.frame(team = c("Bulls", "Nuggets", "Celtics", "Lakers"),
                        conference = c("Eastern", "Western", "Eastern", "Western"),
                        player_over_30 = c("Y","N","N","Y"),
                        date_team_formed = c(1966-01-01,1967-01-01,1946-06-06,1947-01-01))

nba_list <- list()
for(i in 1:length(unique(nba_teams$conference))){
  nba_list[[i]] <- filter(nba_teams, conference==unique(nba_teams$conference)[[i]]) %>% as.data.frame()
}
names(nba_list) <- unique(nba_teams$conference)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "NBA Data"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
      box(
        title = "test1",
        uiOutput("detailed_output")

      )))


server <- function(input,output){

 output$detailed_output <- renderUI({
   pan = lapply(1:length(nba_list[['Western']]$team), function(x) 
     tabPanel(nba_list[['Western']]$team[x],
              reactive({
                if(nba_list[['Western']]$player_over_30[x]=='Y'){
                  return(tags$li(nba_list[['Western']]$team[x],icon("file")))
                }
                else{
                  return(tags$li(nba_list[['Western']]$team[x]))
                }
              })))
   do.call(what = shinydashboard::tabBox, args = c(title = "teams", width = 12, height = "200px", pan))
 })}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

However, when I try to run this the dashboard will update, however the tabpanel will not render with the reactive option.  The error message that I receive is that cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'.

This is failing down at the server reactive part but am unsure what to change to remedy this.  Thank you,

Comment: I can help you but you need to cut down your code to absolute bare minimum that captures your problem/concept. Your current code is too much to go through.

Comment: Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do boiled down to just the minimum areas:  data defined, UI and the server portion which is causing the issue.